On start the app, Simulator showing black screen and closed immediately thru Visual Studio For Mac
I was trying to upgrade the SDK for an xamarine mobile application, I am using Visual Studio 2022 and updated the SDK to 17.5 in project property and running the application on xCode 15.4 on IOS Simulator iPhone 15 Pro Max.
Current version is SDK 14.5 and xCode in 14.3 running without any issue.
enter image description here
enter image description here
The issue is, as soon As I start the application, it opens a black screen and close immediately.
enter image description here
enter image description here
Do I need to make any other change to project settings to update the sdk or I am missing something?
I tried to downgrade the SDK but as I am working on MacInCloud with latest OS and Latest xCode is already installed, so can not installed minor version of xCode.
